# Is there any good solution for master nodes of a redis cluster always being unbalanced distributed?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I deployed a redis cluster with 4 cloud servers. And the initial distribution of master nodes was 4-4-2-2. And it was to make the redis cluster could still work no matter if any server was down. Because the number of surviving master nodes would always be more than half of the total number of master nodes, new master nodes could be elected. However, during cluster running, the master nodes in the cluster always tend to go to one certain server. Maybe it’s because this server has better resources than others. So the distribution of master nodes may become unbalanced such as 7-2-2-1 or 9-2-1-0. And if the server with the most master nodes goes down, the redis cluster goes down. The availability of the cluster is reduced. My current solution is to restore it to 4-4-2-2 by manually run cluster failover takeover when the distribution is unbalanced. And I want to know if there are other solutions to prevent the distribution of master nodes from being unbalanced, or to make the cluster to recover itself from an unbalanced state to a balanced state.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is there any reason you don't just put four master nodes on these four cloud servers?  Are you using Kuberenetes to schedule the master nodes around?

Comment: Hi, I use OpenShift. But I'm just a beginner and don't know much about it. Actually I also don’t know redis very well. Back to the question, even if I deploy one master node on each server and the initial distribution is 1-1-1-1, I think it also tends to become unbalanced such as 3-1-0-0. Maybe because the network environment of some servers is not good, the master nodes will tend to go to a better server by the automatic redis failover. My next plan is to write a scheduled script to scan the cluster and execute failover command to restore the cluster to a balanced state if needed.